# Static composer tests fail on fresh install

Tags: magento2

If I clone a fresh copy of magento2 and run `vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/static/phpunit.xml.dist`, the `ComposerTest` fails because each packaged module has a 'version' property.

```
Version must not be specified in the root and package composer JSON files in Git
Failed asserting that object of class "stdClass" does not have attribute "version".
```

Am I missing something? I could mark the `ComposerTest` as skipped but it seems a bit messy. Does `php bin/magento dev:tests:run static` handle multiple composer files any better?

Answer (score 0):

It emerged that, on older branches of `magento/magento2`, Magento modules [specify a version in their composer files](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Analytics/composer.json#L25), which results in the above error. However, on the latest `2.3-develop` branch the composer files do *not* display a version and therefore pass the `ComposerTest` - so I'm testing against that going forward.